# Форма обратной связи не обрабатывает кириллицу

Tags: php

Есть сайт, на котором такая проблема: форма обратной связи на сайте не обрабатывает кириллицу, пишет: Введите пожалуйста "...любое поле в к тором кириллицу написали..." Вашего сообщения. В php  не силён. Подскажите пожалуйста название функции, которая за это отвечает, я её найду и попробую поковыряться, пока что нашел такой код на сайте, если проблема кроется в нём, может подскажите на какой строчке проблема? Что нужно добавить, что бы всё работало хорошо:

```
<?php
Error_Reporting(E_ALL);

function stop_cron_mail()
  {
  if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')
    {   
    exec("schtasks /delete /tn cron_mail /f");
    }
  else
    {
    $crontab= shell_exec('crontab -l');

    $crontab = preg_replace ('~\*/1 .*cron_mail.php~i',"",$crontab);
     if (empty($crontab))
        shell_exec('crontab -r');
    else
      {
    $filename=dirname(__FILE__).'/cron_tmp';
    $handle= fopen($filename,'w');
    fwrite($handle,trim($crontab)."\n");
    fclose($handle);

    shell_exec('crontab '.$filename);
    }
    unlink ($filename); 
    }   
  }
$path=dirname(__FILE__);
include "$path/../engine/cfg.php";
$res=mysql_query("select * from msg_offset");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($res);
 if (mysql_num_rows($res)!=1)
   {
   mysql_query("delete from msg_offset");
   mysql_query("insert into msg_offset values (0)");
   $offset=0;
  }
 else
  $offset=$row[0];
$result=mysql_query("select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from msg_tmp join msg_queue using(msg_id) limit $offset, $msg_in_pack");
$result1=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select FOUND_ROWS()"));
$count= $result1[0];
if ((isset($_GET['info'])&& !$cron_mail)|| ($cron_mail&& !isset($_GET['info'])))
{
if ($offset<=$count)
  {
$headers = "From: ".$adminmail."\n";
       $headers .= "Reply-to: ".$adminmail."\n";
       $headers .= "X-Sender: < http://".$cfgURL." >\n";
       $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\n";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $mail = $row['mail'];
      $subj= $row['msg_subj'];
      $body= $row['msg_text'];
      $msg_id=$row['msg_id'];
          if (mail($mail, $subj, $body, $headers))
        mysql_query("update msg_queue set is_send=1 where mail='$mail' and msg_id=$msg_id");
      else
        mysql_query("update msg_queue set is_send=2 where mail='$mail' and msg_id=$msg_id");
  }
  $cur_position=($offset+$msg_in_pack)<=$count ? $offset+$msg_in_pack : $count+1;
  mysql_query("update msg_offset set offset=$cur_position");
  } 
else
  {
  mysql_query("delete from msg_queue where is_send=1");
  mysql_query ("delete from msg_tmp where msg_id not in (select distinct msg_id from msg_queue where is_send in (0,2))");

  if ($cron_mail)
    stop_cron_mail();
  }
}
$res = mysql_query("select * from msg_tmp join msg_queue using(msg_id) where is_send=2");
  $err=mysql_num_rows($res);
$json['all']=$count; 
$json['offset']=$cur_position? $cur_position : $offset;  
$json['err']=$err;
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

- код с еще одного файла:

  ```
  if (@!defined('ENGINE_GOLDSVET'))
    header('location: /adm');
  $action = isset($_GET['action'])? $_GET['action']: false;
  if ($action=='save') 
    {
    $subj=strip_tags ($_POST['subj']);
    $body= strip_tags ($_POST['body'],'<strong>, <p>, <br>');
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);
    if ($subj && $body)
      {
      if (mysql_query("update mail_tmp set subj='$subj', body='$body' where id=$id"))
        echo '<p class="erok">'.$lang['success'].'</p>';
      else
        echo "<p class='er'>".$lang['db_error']."</p>";
      }
    else  
      echo "<p class='er'>".$lang['mail_err']."</p>";
    }



  $res= mysql_query("SELECT * from mail_tmp");
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    echo '<FIELDSET style="border: solid #505E6B 1px; padding: 10px;">
            <LEGEND><b>'.$row['title'].':</b></LEGEND>

            <form action="?a=email&action=save&id='.$row['id'].'" method="post">
              <table width=100%  align="center" border="0" >
                  <tr>
                        <td><b>'.$lang['mail_subj'].':</b><br /></td>
                        <td align="left">
                    <input class="inp" style="width: 100%;" type="text" name="subj" size="100"  maxlength="100" value="'.$row['subj'].'"> 
                    </td>

                 </tr>';
        echo '<tr><td colspan=2>
            <textarea class="inp" id="mail_'.$row['id'].'" name="body" style="width: 844px;" rows="25">'.$row['body'].'</textarea>
          </td></tr>';         

      echo '</table>
  <table align="center" width=100% border="0">
      <tr>
          <td align="right"><br><input type="submit" value="ÎÊ" name="submit" id="submit" class="fader"/></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
            </form>';
      echo '</FIELDSET> <br />';
    }
  echo "<script>
        CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
        </script>";  
  ?>
  ```

Так же предоставляю саму форму:

```
<form action="/?GE={$ge}&action=submit" id="loginPhoneForm" action="" method="post">
    <div class="title-text">{$lang['contact_page']['your_name']}  </div>
    <br />
                                    <div class="input-back">
                                        <div class="input-back-left-login"></div>
                                        <div class="input-back-right"></div>
                                        <div class="input-back-center">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" class="input-field"  maxlength="12" value="{$login}" {if $login} disabled {/if}></td>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    <div class="title-text">{$lang['contact_page']['your_email']}  </div>
    <br />
                                    <div class="input-back">
                                        <div class="input-back-left-login"></div>
                                        <div class="input-back-right"></div>
                                        <div class="input-back-center">
                                            <input type="text" name="mail" class="input-field"  maxlength="30" value="{$user_mail}" {if $user_mail} disabled {/if}></td>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    <div class="title-text">{$lang['contact_page']['subj']}  </div>
    <br />
                                    <div class="input-back">
                                        <div class="input-back-left-login"></div>
                                        <div class="input-back-right"></div>
                                        <div class="input-back-center">
                                            <input type="text" name="subj" class="input-field"  maxlength="50" value=""></td>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    <div class="title-text">{$lang['contact_page']['text']}  </div>
    <br /><br />        
                <textarea type="text" name="textform" maxlength="1175" style="width:860px; height: 170px;"></textarea>              

                                    <br /><br />

        <img style="float:left; margin: 5px;" src="/engine/captcha.php" width="70" height="25" border="0" maxlength="5" alt="{$lang['enter_captcha']}">
        <input size="10" type="text" name="code" style="margin: 4px;width: 77px; height: 21px;">

                                    <br />
        <a href="javascript: document.getElementById('loginPhoneForm').submit()">
                                    <div class="form-buttons">
                                        <div class="b-gold">
                                            <div class="l"></div>
                                            <div class="c">
                                            <div class="b-t-type4">{$lang['submit']}</div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="r"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" value="Submit" />
</div>
         </a>
        </form>
```

Нашёл еще один четвёртый файл, может всё же в нём проблема, посмотрите пожалуйста:

```
<?php
    $page = 'contacts';
    $file = 'contacts.php';
    $idpg = 11;

    $templ_name='contacts.tpl';

    $smarty->assign('user_mail', $user_mail);

    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'","",substr($_GET['action'],0,6))): false;

    if($action == "submit") {
        $name       = isset($_POST['name'])?htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'","",substr($_POST['name'],0,50))):$login;
        $mail       = isset($_POST['mail'])?htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'","",substr($_POST['mail'],0,50))):$user_mail;
        $subj       = isset($_POST['subj'])?htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'","",substr($_POST['subj'],0,100))):false;
        $textform   = isset($_POST['textform'])?htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'","",substr($_POST['textform'],0,10240))):false;
        $code       = isset($_POST['code'])?htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'","",substr($_POST['code'],0,5))):false;

    $error=false;

        if(!$name) {
                $_SESSION['messages'][]=array('er',$lang['enter_login']);
        $error=true;
        }
        elseif(!$mail) {
                $_SESSION['messages'][]=array('er',$lang['email']);
        $error=true;
        }
        elseif(!$subj) {
                $_SESSION['messages'][]=array('er',$lang['enter_subj']);
        $error=true;
        }
        elseif(!$textform) {
                $_SESSION['messages'][]=array('er',$lang['enter_message']);
        $error=true;
        }
        elseif(!preg_match("/^[Г -ГїГЂ-ГџВёВЁa-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,20}@(([Г -ГїГЂ-ГџВёВЁa-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+(com|net|org|mil|edu|gov|arpa|info|biz|[a-z]{2})|[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})$/is",$mail)) {
                $_SESSION['messages'][]=array('er',$lang['preg_match']);
        $error=true;
        } 
    elseif(!mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM captcha WHERE sid = '".$sid."' AND ip = '".getip()."' AND code = '".$code."'"))) {
            $_SESSION['messages'][]=array('er',$lang['no_captcha']);
      $error=true;
        } 
    if(!$error) 
      {

            $headers = "From: ".$mail."\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-to: ".$mail."\n";
            $headers .= "X-Sender: < http://".$cfgURL." >\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\n";

      $row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from mail_tmp where id=9")); 
      $subject = $row['subj'];
      $text=$row['body'];
      //Г§Г Г¬ГҐГ­ГЁГ¬ ГЇГ®Г¤Г±ГІГ Г­Г®ГўГ®Г·Г­Г»ГҐ ГІГҐГЈГЁ
        $text= str_replace('{%username%}',$name, $text);
        $text= str_replace('{%subj%}',$subj, $text);
        $text= str_replace('{%ip%}',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $text);
        $text= str_replace('{%text%}',$textform, $text);
            $text= str_replace('{%URL%}',$cfgURL, $text);

            $send = mail($adminmail,$subject,$text,$headers);


      $send=user_mail (9,1,array('subj'=>$subj,'text'=>$textform, 'username'=>$name, 'ip'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],'usermail'=>$mail),$mail);    //1 - Id Г Г¤Г¬ГЁГ­Г 
            if(!$send) {
                $_SESSION['messages'][]=array('er',$lang['mailserver_error']);
            } else {

                $_SESSION['messages'][]=array('erok',$lang['message_send']);

                $name       = "";
                $mail       = "";
                $subj       = "";
                $textform   = "";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

И еще, я не пойму почему в разных редакторах показывается разный код?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Валерий, в переведенном вами коде я не вижу форму отправки сообщения, во втором блоке если я правильно понял, форма для массовой отправки сообщений из админки, или у вас именно там и проблема?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Я дополнил вопрос самой формой.

Comment: @Winteriscoming Нашёл еще один четвёртый файл, может всё же в нём проблема, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 4):

Если латиницу/цифры без проблем обрабатывает, а кириллицу не понимает, дело в кодировке.
Как правило идёт война CP1251 / UTF8.

Тут важны несколько моментов сразу:

- кодировка по умолчанию в php (см. php.ini)
- кодировка по умолчанию в БД (см. my.ini для mysql)
- кодировка в которой сохранены исходники, т.е. php и прочие шаблоны/css/js на сервере
- кодировка по умолчанию веб-сервера (для apache см. httpd.conf
- не лишне заглянуть в html-шаблон страницы, посмотреть что там тыкается, если вообще есть, в `<head><meta ... Content-Type`

Если всё это одна и та же кодировка (в норме), то обычно подобных проблем не возникает.

Да, и надо учитывать, что некоторые фреймворки и спецификации могут требовать кодировку UTF8 даже если у вас всё прочее на WIN1251. Например, JSON-овый ajax у jQuery таков.

Comment: По всем пунктам стоит кодировака 1251, по поводу "кодировка в которой сохранены исходники, т.е. php и прочие шаблоны/css/js на сервере" не уверен. А и еще, когда пытаюсь сохранить файл email.php в кодировке 1251 выдаёт ошибку: "not all characters are representable in Cyrillic (Windows 1251), falling back to UTF-8", это может что то означать?

Comment: Возможно именно в этом и дело. А какой редактор используете? Если например лёгкий Notepad++, то там есть возможность увидеть и текущую кодировку файла, и преобразовать из одной в другую одним кликом пункта меню.

Comment: Дело было в value="ÎÊ". Оно так показалось у меня в программе "sublime text", и в этом же sublime text выскакивала ошибка при сохранении. В вопросе Вы можете увидеть этот код (во втором файле). Когда я открыл этот файл в Notepad++, то этот код был виден так: value="OK". Я открыл sublime text и в ручную вписал вместо ÎÊ - OK и тогда sublime text сохранил без ошибки, но всё ровно это не помогло. Я открыл в Notepad++ все три файла и указал там кодировку 1251, но так же это не помогло :( может у Вас есть еще какие то идеи?

Comment: Скорее всего не тот php файл смотрите. Ищите по именам инпутов, чтоб был весь основной набор из формы: name, mail, subj, textform.. Т.е. где-то в коде будет или $_POST['textform'] и прчие, или $_REQUEST['textform']

Comment: Нашёл еще один четвёртый файл, может всё же в нём проблема, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Вот этот файл как раз что нужен.

Comment: (неудобная обработка энтера тут в комментариях, мол отправить - нет, нет, и ещё раз нет, это не ирка - я лишь хотел перевести на новую строку)

Comment: elseif(!preg_match("/^[Г -ГїГЂ-ГџВёВЁa-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,20}@(([Г -ГїГЂ-ГџВёВЁa-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+

Comment: Я не понял, что Вы имели ввиду?

Comment: (И "редактировать не нажать у комментария, бесит)
В общем, в той строчке выше и есть проблема. Там автор подразумевал такое:
elseif(!preg_match("/^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,20}@(([а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+... - один вариантов регулярки для валидации email.

Я бы посоветовал взять её всю и выкинуть, заменив эту строку с
elseif(!preg_match("/^[Г -ГїГЂ-ГџВёВЁa-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,20}@(([Г -ГїГЂ-ГџВёВЁa-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+(com|net|org|mil|edu|gov|arpa|info|biz|[a-z]{2})|[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})$/is",$mail)) {
на
elseif(!preg_match("/^[^@]{1,20}@[a-z0-9\-_.]+$/is",$mail)) {

Comment: Ну а разный код в редакторах показываться может, потому как кодировка нигде явно не прописана*, и тогда редакторы по-разному могут "догадываться", какая же тут правильная, или иметь разные настройки по-умолчанию в какой кодировке считать написанными открываемые файлы. (за исключением, разве что файлов вида UTF8-with-BOM - там первыми тремя байтами файла идёт специальный символ Byte Order Mask, по нему редакторы понимают, что это точно UTF8[withBOM]) ...... Например, сохраняя сурс где "нет кириллицы" что в кодировке Win1251, что в UTF8 (без BOM) получим идентичные до байта файлы.

Comment: Заменил, но всё ровно пишет, что бы ввели что то в поля: "Тема" и "Текст вашего сообщения"

Comment: А файл после этого был сохранен в 1251?

Comment: Да, в sublime text

Comment: И ещё, в любом интересующем месте всегда можно добавить строчку -- echo "Hello people! My var=$var \n"; -- для любой интересующей простой переменной $var. Для печати массивов и объектов можно пользоваться функциями print_r($var) или var_dump($var). Пошагово натыкайте, и увидите где оно перестаёт работать как ожидается.

Comment: Ой не ) это не про меня )

Answer (score 2):

Код который вы прикрепили, больше подходит на какой-то обработчик крона, скорее всего должен быть другой код, куда отправляется форма. Посмотрите в html в теге form, куда она отправляется (поле action).

На сервере чтобы работать с кириллицей используют обычно строковые функции которые начинаются с префикса `mb_` (http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php). Чтобы точно сказать в чем проблема, надо найти кусок кода который валидирует данные вашей формы, так сложно сказать, много вариантов может быть

**Обновление**

Единственное место, где есть проверки – это или `if ($subj && $body)`, или 
`(mysql_query("update mail_tmp set subj='$subj', body='$body' where id=$id"))`. В первом случае подобное означает, что вы отправляете скорее всего пустое поле или `subj` или `body`, во втором случае – ваши данные не были найдены в базе.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, посмотрите еще раз пожалуйста

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов я дополнил ответ. код плохо написан, сложно с ходу сказать в чем дело, но две основные проверки я вам описал

Comment: Я нашел html формы, дополнил ответ. action получается 'action="/?GE={$ge}&action=submit"'

Comment: Нашёл еще один четвёртый файл, может всё же в нём проблема, посмотрите пожалуйста